# Why is Custom DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider's CreateMetadata never being called?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a custom provider by inheriting the `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` and overriding the `CreateMetadata` method:

```
public class CustomMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, 
        Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, 
        Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        //... code not included for brevity but execution never gets here
    }
}
```

Then I registered it in `Global.asax` within `MvcApplication` class:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // Other code...
        System.Web.ModelBinding.ModelMetadataProviders.Current = 
            new CustomMetadataProvider();
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint and the registration above is executing and `Current` is being set.

**Problem/Question**

The `CreateMetadata` method is never being called. What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the wrong property in your `Global.asax.cs` file. Instead of:

```
System.Web.ModelBinding.ModelMetadataProviders.Current = 
        new CustomMetadataProvider();
```

It should just be this:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = 
        new CustomMetadataProvider();
```

Which if you really want to provide the full qualifier is actually:

```
System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadataProviders.Current = 
        new CustomMetadataProvider();
```

Comment: I have tried that already and actually that is not how it is done. That will give you this error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'CustomMetadataProvider' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadataProvider'`

Comment: That's very odd, are you sure your class is inheriting from `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`? Try it with the fill namespace `System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`

Comment: @CodingYoshi - David is right. You must be subclassing [System.Web.ModelBinding.DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.modelbinding.dataannotationsmodelmetadataprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) it should be [System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelmetadataprovider(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: Thank you! Yes you are right. But how did you figure this out, I spent hours searching for this.

Comment: Many years of experience, thousands of hours practising my Google-fu and a smidgen of already having that snippet of code from an old project ;)

Comment: I guess my Monkey-Style is not as good as your Google-fu style:( Cool. Thanks again.

Comment: @DavidG Please see if you can help with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714556/combining-multiple-validation-attributes-not-working) question.