# Customized DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have many properties that require 1 or more validation attributes, like the following:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Some]
    [StringLength(6)]
    [CustomRequired] // more attributes...
    public string Truck { get; set; }
}
```

Please note all the above annotations work.

I do not want to write that all the time because whenever `Some` is applied, all other attributes are also applied to the property. I want to be able to do this:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Some]
    public string Truck { get; set; }
}
```

Now this is doable by inheriting; therefore, I wrote a custom `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` and overrode the `CreateMetadata`. This looks for anything that is decorated with `Some` and then adds more attributes to it:

```
public class TruckNumberMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var attributeList = attributes.ToList();
        if (attributeList.OfType<SomeAttribute>().Any())
        {
            attributeList.Add(new StringLengthAttribute(6));
            attributeList.Add(new CustomRequiredAttribute());
        }

        return base.CreateMetadata(attributeList, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
    }
}
```

These are the attributes in case it helps:

```
public class CustomRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public CustomRequiredAttribute()
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = "Required";
    }
}
public class SomeAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public SomeAttribute()
        : base(@"^[1-9]\d{0,5}$")
    {
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Truck)
```

HTML Rendered:

```
<input name="Truck" id="Truck" type="text" value="" 
    data-val-required="The Truck field is required." 
    data-val-regex-pattern="^[1-9]\d{0,5}$" 
    data-val-regex="The field Truck must match the regular expression '^[1-9]\d{0,5}$'." 
    data-val="true">
</input>
```

**Problems/Questions**

1. The `CustomRequired` was applied. But why does it pick up the message from the base class `RequiredAttribute` if I am using `CustomRequired`. The `data-val-required` should just say *Required*.
2. The `StringLenth` of 6 chars is not applied. There is no sign of anything rendered for `StringLength`, why?

Comment: With regard to (1), have you registered your custom attributes in `global.asax.cs`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes I have registered them. When I use them on my model directly, they work. You can actually take the code and it will reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have no `Required` applied to the model so it is definitely picking it up from the custom provider but for some reason the error message is not picked up.

Answer (score 3):

What your custom `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` is doing is creating/modifying the `ModelMetada` associated with your property.

If you inspect the [ModelMetadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata(v=vs.118).aspx) class you will note that it contains properties such as `string DisplayName` and `string DisplayFormatString` which are set based on the application of the `[Display]` and `[DisplayFormat]` attributes. It also contains a `bool IsRequired` attribute that determines if the value of a property is required (a bit more on that later).

It does not contain anything relating to a regular expression or the maximum length, or indeed anything related to validation (except the `IsRequired` property and the `ModelType` which is used to validate that that the value can be converted to the `type`).

It is the `HtmlHelper` methods that are responsible for generating the html that is passed to the view. To generate the `data-val-*` attributes, your `TextBoxFor()` method internally calls the `GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes()` method of the `HtmlHelper` class which in turn calls methods in the `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider` class which ultimately generate a `Dictionary` of the `data-val` attribute names and values used to generate the html.

I'll leave it to you to explore the source code if you want more detail (refer links below) but to summarize, it gets a collection of all attributes applied to your `Truck` property that inherit from `ValidationAttribute` to build the dictionary. In your case the only `ValidationAttribute` is `[Some]` which derives from `RegularExpressionAttribute` so the `data-val-regex` and `data-val-regex-pattern` attributes are added.

But because you have added your `CustomRequiredAttribute` in the `TruckNumberMetadataProvider`, the `IsRequired` property of the `ModelMetadata` has been set to `true`. If you insect the `GetValidators()` of `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider` you will see that a `RequiredAttribute` is automatically added to the collection of attributes because you have not applied one to the property. The relevant snippet of code is

```
if (AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes && metadata.IsRequired && !attributes.Any(a => a is RequiredAttribute))
{
    attributes = attributes.Concat(new[] { new RequiredAttribute() });
}
```

which results in the `data-val-required` attribute being added to the html (and it uses the default message because it knows nothing about your `CustomRequiredAttribute`)

Source code files to get you started if you want to understand the internal workings

1. [HtmlHelper.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/HtmlHelper.cs) - refer `GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes()` methods at line 413
2. [ModelValidatorProviders.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ModelValidatorProviders.cs) - gets the various ValidatorProviders used for validation
3. [DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.cs) - the ValidatorProvider for `ValidationAttributes`

One possible solution if you really want to use just one single `ValidationAttribute` would be to have it implement `IClientValidatable` and in the `GetClientValidationRules()` method, add rules, for example

```
var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
{
    ValidationType = "required",
    ErrorMessage = "Required"
}
```

which will be read by the `ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider` (and delete your `TruckNumberMetadataProvider` class). However that will create a maintenance nightmare so I recommend you just add the 3 validation attributes to your property

Comment: This helps and I will look into it after the weekend. Thanks.